# Como permitir acessar apenas a pagina principal pela url

Tags: apache

Olá, por exemplo, no `/var/www/Site` eu tenho a pasta `paginas` e o arquivo `index.php`, gostaria de quando acessar site.com a unica pasta que o usuario tivesse acesso seria a `Site` que chamaria o arquivo index, porem não pudesse acessar outras paginas digitando por exemplo `site.com/paginas/teste.php`.

Answer (score -1):

Crie um arquivo .htaccess (sem nome mesmo, só com essa extensão).

Abra no bloco de notas, e digite:

DirectoryIndex index.php

## Options Indexes